# RPi3 with SainSmart 5" TFT touchscreen doesn't work

Tags: touchscreen, pitft

I bought a [SainSmart 5" TFT with resistive touch](http://www.sainsmart.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-lcd/5-inch-800x480-hdmi-touch-lcd-screen-display-for-raspberry-pi-pi2-model-b-a.html) to attach to my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. The display works fine, though I had to set an HDMI_CVT parameter in /boot/config.txt in order to expand the display from 480x600 to 480x800. But I can't get the touchscreen to work. The SainSmart web site wants me to download a custom kernel, which I am loath to do. I found [these instructions](https://alexander201314.wordpress.com/2015/08/07/review-guide-sainsmart-5%E2%80%B3-inch-hdmi-touch-display/) for setting up the touchscreen. I followed the instructions in Step 4 to install touchscreen support in the kernel, then performed the first two items in Step 5 to create device rules, and rebooted. I do not see a device at /dev/input/touchscreen, as the instructions imply, nor does the touchscreen work. I went on and installed the packages near the bottom of Step 5, and ran the command to calibrate the touchscreen, but nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me how to get the touchscreen to work?

Comment: there is a software driver that fixes this without having to use a custom kernel. I'm looking now but I had a difficult time finding it originally. I'll post a link when I get home if somebody else doesn't in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to install a custom kernel, you can use [this driver](http://repository.sainsmart.com/index.php?share/file&user=bbu_sainsmart&sid=oeMDUjWv), and then follow [these instructions](http://wiki.sainsmart.com/index.php/SainSmart_5_inch_TFT_LCD_800*480_Touch_Screen_Display_for_Raspberry_Pi2/3).

Specifically, because you have the 5" model, you'll use the following command after following the first few steps of extracting the driver tarball and changing into its directory:

```
sudo ./LCD5-show
```